# Story in which rain melts buildings

Tags: story-identification

I'm searching for the identity of a short story. My memories of it are vague, so these details are uncertain:

- It begins with rain. The author notes that the rain tastes normal.
- The rain melts all of the buildings in the city.
- At the end, bears arrive. The story ends on this note. ("But then the bears came")

I read it approximately a decade ago, though the story could have been older.

Comment: Can you recall anything else? For example, why do the bears arrive? When did you read this?

Comment: IIRC, the bears were not mentioned until the final sentence, which was something like "But then the bears came...". I can't recall any more details, unfortunately. I read it approximately a decade ago.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've read this... can you provide *any* other details (no matter how fuzzy) that might narrow it down? Was it first-person or third-person? Male or female protagonist, or no protagonist? Any other effects of the rain? Anything odd besides the rain? Any character traits that stand out? Any sense of the time period in which it occurs? How many pages, roughly?

Comment: @Otis I think the narration was first person, don't recall that any personal details were given. I don't think the rain was mentioned other than tasting normal but melting the buildings. I think the buildings were skyscrapers (though I may have just imagined that) which would make it modern-ish or later. No idea how long it was.